# Home Directory in Ubuntu app in Windows

Tags: directory, home-directory

I have recently install ubuntu from windows store in windows 10 PC.But after installing I have not find the home directory of ubuntu. How can I found that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the location of the Ubuntu files within your windows file system please check your Documents/Virtual Machines path. It should save there any virtual machines you created

Comment: Can I create any home directory in this ubuntu app as in case of ubuntu OS